# how to do REST GET or PUT with objectid of mongoose generated document in angular

Tags: angularjs, express

having a small issue with a basic about RESTful API. I have this api below for PUT request on the express server and I would like to do http request from client side in angular to get a right result. the API works when I tries to locate /api/users/objectID directly but I am having issue coming up with an idea on how to pass the id on the client side function. what will be a good practice and way of doing this?

```
//client side code.
    userService.saveFavorite = function(id, currentUser){
    $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: '/api/users/'+id,
      data: {
        favorite : currentUser.uid
      }
    }).then(function (res){
      console.log('the update has been saved', res);
    }, function (err){
      console.log('error occured while updating', err);
    })
  }

//server side API
app.put('/api/users/:id', function (req, res){
  return User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    //just update the favorite
    user.favorite = req.body.favorite;

    return user.save(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("updated");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
      return res.send(user);
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need to know the ObjectId on the client side as such, but you will need the string that it wraps around. Where Mongoose uses ObjectId('1234567') your client will work with '1234567'.

So, when the client wants to know about '1234567', you will need to reconvert the Id passed by Angular into ObjectId used by Mongoose. That's easy in practise:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req, res){
  return User.findById({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function (err, user){
    if(!err){
      return res.send(user);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks. do you mean I just use this on client side? I am new and I thought I don't want to make the client side directly deal with the DB. any comments are appreciated.

Comment: oh got it. thanks. but actually when I try like /api/users/objectID manually from the client side, it returns the user object. My question was actually about how to submit the objectID properly from the client side. how do I know which ID to submit from the client side when I want to submit the user object id stored in the DB? not sure how to retreive the id at the first place? any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't worry. The `ObjectId` is stripped off of what is sent to the client, so there you just deal with strings. But you have to reattach it before you ask Mongoose to save, otherwise it will create a secondary entry with `_id:1234567` instead of _id:ObjectId(1234567)`

Comment: thanks. I am still a bit confused. let me update my question to try to clarify what I want to solve.

Comment: Hi Simon, I updated the question. hmm sorry but I am still stuck a bit. so my question is when I want to do PUT request on the client side to modify a specific user's data in the DB, on the client side how do I submit it properly with the right ID. is it like I should save the id on the client side from the response data when logging in so I can retrieve the id easily? or another good way of doing it?